# Unset environment variable in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How do I **unset** an environmental variable in Jupyter Notebook?  I set the variables using a `.env` file that is loaded by:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('./.env')
```

After changing the `.env` file and rerunning the import/load does the variable stays the same (the old version).  I tried setting the environment variable to `None` using the magic command but it's literally now None instead of blank.  I didnt see any unset command at https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL/DR**; You can undo changes made by `load_dotenv` manually; by storing the original `os.environ` to a variable, then overwriting `os.environ` with it later. Alternatively, you can delete envvars with `del`.

---

Let's say you have two .env files for development and production (note that `FOOGULAR_VERBOSE` is defined only in `.env.dev`):

**.env.dev**

```
ROOT_URL=localhost/dev
FOOGULAR_VERBOSE=True
```

**.env.prod**

```
ROOT_URL=example.org
```

You can store the base environment to a variable, then load `.env.dev` like such:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

# Preserve the base environment before load_dotenv
base_environ = os.environ.copy()

# Then load an .env file
load_dotenv('./.env.dev')
print(os.environ)
```

At this stage, the envvars are:

```
ROOT_URL='localhost/dev'
FOOGULAR_VERBOSE='True'
```

To switch to the production environment, revert to the `base_environ` first, then load `.env.prod`, like this:

```py
os.environ = base_environ  # Reset envvars
load_dotenv('./.env.prod') # Then load another .env file
```

Now the envvars look like this:

```
ROOT_URL=example.org
```

---

Another method is to delete `os.environ['MY_VARIABLE']` manually, with the `del` statement:

```py
del os.environ['FOOGULAR_VERBOSE']
```

Comment: And it was that easy.  I didn't realize that environment variables would respond to a del.  I assumed since they are 'special' they would need something special.  Thanks!

Comment: Wait so do environment variable files not need to be named `.env`?  You had a double period name as an example.  Is that 'allowed'.  I (again) assumed that it had to be a specifically named file like git_ignore.

Comment: @DChaps The `load_dotenv` function accepts arbitrary `dotenv_path` as the first argument (see [the source code](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/blob/914c68ef0e4c2c085d2753f5cbbf304852f37850/src/dotenv/main.py#L307)), so it does not need to be named `.env`. If `load_dotenv()` is invoked without arguments, it automatically looks for a file named `.env` (see [the doc's usage example](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv#getting-started)); in this case, it is helpful to name the env file as `.env`.